# Ads showing up in iOS simulator but not in App Store

Tags: ios7, ads, chartboost

So i tested my app in the ios 7 simulator in xcode and all my ads would show up.  Now that I submitted my app in the App Store, they will not show up anywhere. App went live 6 hours ago.  Any ideas as to how i can fix this or why this is happening? Using chartboost, applovin and revmob

Comment: Can you share your ad code?

Comment: Can you post some logs?